# Threshold summing in rails/postgres

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, arel

I'm making a walkathon rails app. Each walker is sponsored by people who pledge money per lap up to a maximum amount.

I have a table called `sponsorships` that has columns `walker_id`, `amount_per_lap`, and `max_amount`. I want to write a SQL query to determine how much money a walker has raised.

There is also a `walkers` table that has `id`, `name`, and `laps` columns.

I know this isn't valid SQL, but I wanted something like this, but don't know the best way to do it. The walker_id and laps could be provided before executing the query.

> SELECT SUM(MIN(Laps * sponsorships.amount_per_lap, sponsorships.max_amount)) FROM sponsorships
>   where sponsorships.walker_id = 1;

I'm making this in rails, so I was trying to figure out how to do something like this in Arel, but couldn't figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*Edit*: clarifying the `walkers` table.

*Edit2*: Accidentally had max instead of min in the pseudo code

Comment: the walker has a laps column - I'll edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the SQL you're looking for is this:

```
select w.id, w.name, sum(least(w.laps * s.amount_per_lap, s.max_amount))
from walkers w
join sponsorships s on w.id = s.walker_id
group by w.id, w.name
```

The [`least` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST) is what applies your "no more than `max_amount`" condition. Translating that to AR should be a simple matter for you now that you know what to SELECT; I tend to go straight to SQL for anything like this.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the least function.

Comment: @Cyrus: `least` and `greatest` are surprisingly useful but not very well know.

Comment: I'm surprised more people don't talk about them. So useful!

Comment: @Cyrus: I think most programmers have an irrational fear of SQL so they don't get to anything more complicated than `select * from t where a=b` with maybe a GROUP BY thrown in now and then. SQL requires you to think differently than most languages: you describe what you want rather than telling the computer what to do. Many developers only want to work with one language at a time so SQL is too strange. [You should not have a favorite weapon...](http://www.bookoffiverings.com/EarthBook.htm). That's my preaching for today :)

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like:

```
class Sponsorship < ActiveRecord::Base
  name
  walker_id
  amount_per_lap
  max_amount

class Walker < ActiveRecord::Base
  name
  number_of_laps

walker_sum = 0
walker=walker.find(1) # For 1 walker.
walker.sponsorships.each do |sponsor| #
  walker_sum+= 
  min((sponsor.amount_per_lap * walker.number_of_laps), (sponsor.max_amount))
end
```

Comment: gotcha. is the only way to do this with n+1 db queries? i'm hoping there's a way to calculate this in the database, but if not I'll fall back on what you have written here. thanks for your help.

Comment: Updated to use min instead of max !